# Partition 3TB disk as 1 primary partition or as 2*1.5TB in a LVM?

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I have a Debian box that I am about to restore from backup since the old 2TB disk crashed and died.

So I have a new 3TB disk that will replace him, but when I filled the 3TB partition with the same data it actually seems to takes up more space, probably since there is a lot of small files.

Would it be more optimal to partition the drive in 2 or 3 primary partitions 
(size 1TB or 1.5TB) and use them as 1 LVM partition?

If it matters I plan to use ext4 on this disk.

Comment: maybe you've chosen the wrong cluster/inode size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any advantages to creating multiple physical partitions on the same disk and merging them together as one logical volume. It's just added complexity.